# How to Use Collect with Fortran Form expression or How to Convert results of Collect into Fortran Form expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

For example:

`expr = (a0 D11+(a0^2 D11)/2+(a1^2 D11)/4+(a2^2 D11)/4+(a3^2 D11)/4+(a4^2 D11)/4+(a5^2 D11)/4+(a6^2 D11)/4+(a7^2 D11)/4+(a8^2 D11)/4+(d0^2 D11)/2+(d1^2 D11)/4+b0 D12+(b0^2 D12)/2+(b1^2 D12)/4+(b2^2 D12)/4+(b3^2 D12)/4+(b4^2 D12)/4+(b5^2 D12)/4+(b6^2 D12)/4+(b7^2 D12)/4+(b8^2 D12)/4+c0 D13+(c0^2 D13)/2+(c1^2 D13)/4+(c2^2 D13)/4+(c3^2 D13)/4+(c4^2 D13)/4+d0 D14+b0 d0 D14+(b1 d1 D14)/2+(b2 D14 d2)/2+(D11 d2^2)/4+(b3 D14 d3)/2+(D11 d3^2)/4+(b4 D14 d4)/2+(D11 d4^2)/4+(b5 D14 d5)/2+(D11 d5^2)/4+(b6 D14 d6)/2+(D11 d6^2)/4+(b7 D14 d7)/2+(D11 d7^2)/4+(b8 D14 d8)/2+(D11 d8^2)/4+(a1 D14 e1)/2+(D12 e1^2)/4+(a2 D14 e2)/2+(D12 e2^2)/4+(a3 D14 e3)/2+(D12 e3^2)/4+(a4 D14 e4)/2+(D12 e4^2)/4+(a5 D14 e5)/2+(D12 e5^2)/4+(a6 D14 e6)/2+(D12 e6^2)/4+(a7 D14 e7)/2+(D12 e7^2)/4+(a8 D14 e8)/2+(D12 e8^2)/4+(D13 f0^2)/2+(D13 f1^2)/4+(D13 f2^2)/4+(D13 f3^2)/4+(D13 f4^2)/4+(D13 f5^2)/4+(D13 f6^2)/4+(D13 f7^2)/4+(D13 f8^2)/4+(D12 g0^2)/2+(D12 g1^2)/4+(D12 g2^2)/4+(D12 g3^2)/4+(D12 g4^2)/4+(D12 g5^2)/4+(D12 g6^2)/4+(D12 g7^2)/4+(D12 g8^2)/4+D14 g0 h0+(D11 h0^2)/2+(D14 g1 h1)/2+(D11 h1^2)/4+(D14 g2 h2)/2+(D11 h2^2)/4+(D14 g3 h3)/2+(D11 h3^2)/4+(D14 g4 h4)/2+(D11 h4^2)/4+(D13 j0^2)/2+(D13 j1^2)/4+(D13 j2^2)/4+(D13 j3^2)/4+(D13 j4^2)/4+(D13 j5^2)/4+(D13 j6^2)/4+(D13 j7^2)/4+(D13 j8^2)/4+(a1 D11+a0 a1 D11+(a1 a3 D11)/2+(a2 a4 D11)/2+(a3 a5 D11)/2+(a4 a6 D11)/2+(a5 a7 D11)/2+(a6 a8 D11)/2+d0 d1 D11+b1 D12+b0 b1 D12+(b1 b3 D12)/2+(b2 b4 D12)/2+(b3 b5 D12)/2+(b4 b6 D12)/2+(b5 b7 D12)/2+(b6 b8 D12)/2+c1 D13+c0 c1 D13+(c1 c3 D13)/2+(c2 c4 D13)/2+b1 d0 D14+d1 D14+b0 d1 D14+(b3 d1 D14)/2+(b4 D14 d2)/2+(d1 D11 d3)/2+(b1 D14 d3)/2+(b5 D14 d3)/2+(b2 D14 d4)/2+(b6 D14 d4)/2+(D11 d2 d4)/2+(b3 D14 d5)/2+(b7 D14 d5)/2+(D11 d3 d5)/2+(b4 D14 d6)/2+(b8 D14 d6)/2+(D11 d4 d6)/2+(b5 D14 d7)/2+(D11 d5 d7)/2+(b6 D14 d8)/2+(D11 d6 d8)/2+D14 e1+a0 D14 e1+(a3 D14 e1)/2+(a4 D14 e2)/2+(a1 D14 e3)/2+(a5 D14 e3)/2+(D12 e1 e3)/2+(a2 D14 e4)/2+(a6 D14 e4)/2+(D12 e2 e4)/2+(a3 D14 e5)/2+(a7 D14 e5)/2+(D12 e3 e5)/2+(a4 D14 e6)/2+(a8 D14 e6)/2+(D12 e4 e6)/2+(a5 D14 e7)/2+(D12 e5 e7)/2+(a6 D14 e8)/2+(D12 e6 e8)/2+D13 f0 f1+(D13 f1 f3)/2+(D13 f2 f4)/2+(D13 f3 f5)/2+(D13 f4 f6)/2+(D13 f5 f7)/2+(D13 f6 f8)/2+D12 g0 g1+(D12 g1 g3)/2+(D12 g2 g4)/2+(D12 g3 g5)/2+(D12 g4 g6)/2+(D12 g5 g7)/2+(D12 g6 g8)/2+D14 g1 h0+D14 g0 h1+(D14 g3 h1)/2+D11 h0 h1+(D14 g4 h2)/2+(D14 g1 h3)/2+(D14 g5 h3)/2+(D11 h1 h3)/2+(D14 g2 h4)/2+(D14 g6 h4)/2+(D11 h2 h4)/2+D13 j0 j1+(D13 j1 j3)/2+(D13 j2 j4)/2+(D13 j3 j5)/2+(D13 j4 j6)/2+(D13 j5 j7)/2+(D13 j6 j8)/2) Cos[angle n])`

In this expression, one part is constant and other part is multiplied by `Cos[angle n]`. I derived this result using `Collect` but do not know how to further convert it into fortran form or otherwise how first i convert expression so that later on, I can use `Collect` to print coefficient?  Also one more point, `Collect[expr, {Cos[n*angle], Sin[n*angle]}]` this expression is for `Cos` and `Sin` terms, How we can use `Collect` to print the constant part also?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the following:
Suppose you put this into a file called f.m :

```
If[FindFile["FeynCalc`"] === $Failed,
   (* as explained here: https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation  *)
   Import["http://users.ph.tum.de/ga57tah/feyncalc/FeynCalcInstallNightly.m"]
];

Needs["FeynCalc`"];

(* assuming you use Fortran 90 or newer*)
$FortranContinuationCharacter = "";

expr=(a0 D11+(a0^2 D11)/2+(a1^2 D11)/4+(a2^2 D11)/4+(a3^2 D11)/4+(a4^2 D11)/4+(a5^2 D11)/4+(a6^2 D11)/4+(a7^2 D11)/4+(a8^2 D11)/4+(d0^2 D11)/2+(d1^2 D11)/4+b0 D12+(b0^2 D12)/2+(b1^2 D12)/4+(b2^2 D12)/4+(b3^2 D12)/4+(b4^2 D12)/4+(b5^2 D12)/4+(b6^2 D12)/4+(b7^2 D12)/4+(b8^2 D12)/4+c0 D13+(c0^2 D13)/2+(c1^2 D13)/4+(c2^2 D13)/4+(c3^2 D13)/4+(c4^2 D13)/4+d0 D14+b0 d0 D14+(b1 d1 D14)/2+(b2 D14 d2)/2+(D11 d2^2)/4+(b3 D14 d3)/2+(D11 d3^2)/4+(b4 D14 d4)/2+(D11 d4^2)/4+(b5 D14 d5)/2+(D11 d5^2)/4+(b6 D14 d6)/2+(D11 d6^2)/4+(b7 D14 d7)/2+(D11 d7^2)/4+(b8 D14 d8)/2+(D11 d8^2)/4+(a1 D14 e1)/2+(D12 e1^2)/4+(a2 D14 e2)/2+(D12 e2^2)/4+(a3 D14 e3)/2+(D12 e3^2)/4+(a4 D14 e4)/2+(D12 e4^2)/4+(a5 D14 e5)/2+(D12 e5^2)/4+(a6 D14 e6)/2+(D12 e6^2)/4+(a7 D14 e7)/2+(D12 e7^2)/4+(a8 D14 e8)/2+(D12 e8^2)/4+(D13 f0^2)/2+(D13 f1^2)/4+(D13 f2^2)/4+(D13 f3^2)/4+(D13 f4^2)/4+(D13 f5^2)/4+(D13 f6^2)/4+(D13 f7^2)/4+(D13 f8^2)/4+(D12 g0^2)/2+(D12 g1^2)/4+(D12 g2^2)/4+(D12 g3^2)/4+(D12 g4^2)/4+(D12 g5^2)/4+(D12 g6^2)/4+(D12 g7^2)/4+(D12 g8^2)/4+D14 g0 h0+(D11 h0^2)/2+(D14 g1 h1)/2+(D11 h1^2)/4+(D14 g2 h2)/2+(D11 h2^2)/4+(D14 g3 h3)/2+(D11 h3^2)/4+(D14 g4 h4)/2+(D11 h4^2)/4+(D13 j0^2)/2+(D13 j1^2)/4+(D13 j2^2)/4+(D13 j3^2)/4+(D13 j4^2)/4+(D13 j5^2)/4+(D13 j6^2)/4+(D13 j7^2)/4+(D13 j8^2)/4+(a1 D11+a0 a1 D11+(a1 a3 D11)/2+(a2 a4 D11)/2+(a3 a5 D11)/2+(a4 a6 D11)/2+(a5 a7 D11)/2+(a6 a8 D11)/2+d0 d1 D11+b1 D12+b0 b1 D12+(b1 b3 D12)/2+(b2 b4 D12)/2+(b3 b5 D12)/2+(b4 b6 D12)/2+(b5 b7 D12)/2+(b6 b8 D12)/2+c1 D13+c0 c1 D13+(c1 c3 D13)/2+(c2 c4 D13)/2+b1 d0 D14+d1 D14+b0 d1 D14+(b3 d1 D14)/2+(b4 D14 d2)/2+(d1 D11 d3)/2+(b1 D14 d3)/2+(b5 D14 d3)/2+(b2 D14 d4)/2+(b6 D14 d4)/2+(D11 d2 d4)/2+(b3 D14 d5)/2+(b7 D14 d5)/2+(D11 d3 d5)/2+(b4 D14 d6)/2+(b8 D14 d6)/2+(D11 d4 d6)/2+(b5 D14 d7)/2+(D11 d5 d7)/2+(b6 D14 d8)/2+(D11 d6 d8)/2+D14 e1+a0 D14 e1+(a3 D14 e1)/2+(a4 D14 e2)/2+(a1 D14 e3)/2+(a5 D14 e3)/2+(D12 e1 e3)/2+(a2 D14 e4)/2+(a6 D14 e4)/2+(D12 e2 e4)/2+(a3 D14 e5)/2+(a7 D14 e5)/2+(D12 e3 e5)/2+(a4 D14 e6)/2+(a8 D14 e6)/2+(D12 e4 e6)/2+(a5 D14 e7)/2+(D12 e5 e7)/2+(a6 D14 e8)/2+(D12 e6 e8)/2+D13 f0 f1+(D13 f1 f3)/2+(D13 f2 f4)/2+(D13 f3 f5)/2+(D13 f4 f6)/2+(D13 f5 f7)/2+(D13 f6 f8)/2+D12 g0 g1+(D12 g1 g3)/2+(D12 g2 g4)/2+(D12 g3 g5)/2+(D12 g4 g6)/2+(D12 g5 g7)/2+(D12 g6 g8)/2+D14 g1 h0+D14 g0 h1+(D14 g3 h1)/2+D11 h0 h1+(D14 g4 h2)/2+(D14 g1 h3)/2+(D14 g5 h3)/2+(D11 h1 h3)/2+(D14 g2 h4)/2+(D14 g6 h4)/2+(D11 h2 h4)/2+D13 j0 j1+(D13 j1 j3)/2+(D13 j2 j4)/2+(D13 j3 j5)/2+(D13 j4 j6)/2+(D13 j5 j7)/2+(D13 j6 j8)/2) Cos[angle n]);

(* see http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Collect2/ *)
new = Collect2[expr, {Sin, Cos}];

(* see http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/Write2/ *)
Write2["out.f", res = new, FormatType -> FortranForm, StringReplace -> {"Cos" -> "cos"}];

FilePrint @ "out.f"
```

Then, e.g. on Linux:

```
In[1]:= <<f.m
downloading http://users.ph.tum.de/ga57tah/feyncalc/fcnightly-head.zip   please wait
Downloading 2 MB from http://users.ph.tum.de/ga57tah/feyncalc/fcnightly-head.zip
Downloading done, installing FeynCalc to /home/rolfm/.Mathematica/Applications
installation of FeynCalc ready.
loading FeynCalc
Loading FeynCalc from /home/rolfm/.Mathematica/Applications/FeynCalc/
$PrePrint is set to FeynCalcForm. Use FI and FC to change the display format.
FeynCalc 9.0.0. For help, type ?FeynCalc, use the help browser or visit www.feyncalc.org.
        res = 2.5D-1*(4D0*a0*D11 + 2D0*a0**2*D11 + a1**2*D11 +
          a2**2*D11 + a3**2*D11 + a4**2*D11 + a5**2*D11 +
          a6**2*D11 + a7**2*D11 + a8**2*D11 +
          2D0*d0**2*D11 + d1**2*D11 + 4D0*b0*D12 +
          2D0*b0**2*D12 + b1**2*D12 + b2**2*D12 +
          b3**2*D12 + b4**2*D12 + b5**2*D12 + b6**2*D12 +
          b7**2*D12 + b8**2*D12 + 4D0*c0*D13 +
          2D0*c0**2*D13 + c1**2*D13 + c2**2*D13 +
          c3**2*D13 + c4**2*D13 + 4D0*d0*D14 +
          4D0*b0*d0*D14 + 2D0*b1*d1*D14 + 2D0*b2*D14*d2 +
          D11*d2**2 + 2D0*b3*D14*d3 + D11*d3**2 +
          2D0*b4*D14*d4 + D11*d4**2 + 2D0*b5*D14*d5 +
          D11*d5**2 + 2D0*b6*D14*d6 + D11*d6**2 +
          2D0*b7*D14*d7 + D11*d7**2 + 2D0*b8*D14*d8 +
          D11*d8**2 + 2D0*a1*D14*e1 + D12*e1**2 +
          2D0*a2*D14*e2 + D12*e2**2 + 2D0*a3*D14*e3 +
          D12*e3**2 + 2D0*a4*D14*e4 + D12*e4**2 +
          2D0*a5*D14*e5 + D12*e5**2 + 2D0*a6*D14*e6 +
          D12*e6**2 + 2D0*a7*D14*e7 + D12*e7**2 +
          2D0*a8*D14*e8 + D12*e8**2 + 2D0*D13*f0**2 +
          D13*f1**2 + D13*f2**2 + D13*f3**2 + D13*f4**2 +
          D13*f5**2 + D13*f6**2 + D13*f7**2 + D13*f8**2 +
          2D0*D12*g0**2 + D12*g1**2 + D12*g2**2 +
          D12*g3**2 + D12*g4**2 + D12*g5**2 + D12*g6**2 +
          D12*g7**2 + D12*g8**2 + 4D0*D14*g0*h0 +
          2D0*D11*h0**2 + 2D0*D14*g1*h1 + D11*h1**2 +
          2D0*D14*g2*h2 + D11*h2**2 + 2D0*D14*g3*h3 +
          D11*h3**2 + 2D0*D14*g4*h4 + D11*h4**2 +
          2D0*D13*j0**2 + D13*j1**2 + D13*j2**2 +
          D13*j3**2 + D13*j4**2 + D13*j5**2 + D13*j6**2 +
          D13*j7**2 + D13*j8**2) +
       5.D-1*(2D0*a1*D11 + 2D0*a0*a1*D11 + a1*a3*D11 +
          a2*a4*D11 + a3*a5*D11 + a4*a6*D11 + a5*a7*D11 +
          a6*a8*D11 + 2D0*d0*d1*D11 + 2D0*b1*D12 +
          2D0*b0*b1*D12 + b1*b3*D12 + b2*b4*D12 +
          b3*b5*D12 + b4*b6*D12 + b5*b7*D12 + b6*b8*D12 +
          2D0*c1*D13 + 2D0*c0*c1*D13 + c1*c3*D13 +
          c2*c4*D13 + 2D0*b1*d0*D14 + 2D0*d1*D14 +
          2D0*b0*d1*D14 + b3*d1*D14 + b4*D14*d2 +
          d1*D11*d3 + b1*D14*d3 + b5*D14*d3 + b2*D14*d4 +
          b6*D14*d4 + D11*d2*d4 + b3*D14*d5 + b7*D14*d5 +
          D11*d3*d5 + b4*D14*d6 + b8*D14*d6 + D11*d4*d6 +
          b5*D14*d7 + D11*d5*d7 + b6*D14*d8 + D11*d6*d8 +
          2D0*D14*e1 + 2D0*a0*D14*e1 + a3*D14*e1 +
          a4*D14*e2 + a1*D14*e3 + a5*D14*e3 + D12*e1*e3 +
          a2*D14*e4 + a6*D14*e4 + D12*e2*e4 + a3*D14*e5 +
          a7*D14*e5 + D12*e3*e5 + a4*D14*e6 + a8*D14*e6 +
          D12*e4*e6 + a5*D14*e7 + D12*e5*e7 + a6*D14*e8 +
          D12*e6*e8 + 2D0*D13*f0*f1 + D13*f1*f3 +
          D13*f2*f4 + D13*f3*f5 + D13*f4*f6 + D13*f5*f7 +
          D13*f6*f8 + 2D0*D12*g0*g1 + D12*g1*g3 +
          D12*g2*g4 + D12*g3*g5 + D12*g4*g6 + D12*g5*g7 +
          D12*g6*g8 + 2D0*D14*g1*h0 + 2D0*D14*g0*h1 +
          D14*g3*h1 + 2D0*D11*h0*h1 + D14*g4*h2 +
          D14*g1*h3 + D14*g5*h3 + D11*h1*h3 + D14*g2*h4 +
          D14*g6*h4 + D11*h2*h4 + 2D0*D13*j0*j1 +
          D13*j1*j3 + D13*j2*j4 + D13*j3*j5 + D13*j4*j6 +
          D13*j5*j7 + D13*j6*j8)*cos(angle*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the value of `expr` from your question, you can extract the coefficient of the $\cos$ function and the constant part as follows:

```
coscoefficient = Coefficient[expr, Cos[angle n]];
constantpart = expr - coscoefficient * Cos[angle n];
```

You can check that indeed your expression `expr` can be reconstructed from those two parts:

```
constantpart + Cos[angle n]*coscoefficient == expr

(* Out: True *)
```

You can then reformat these two parts into Fortran format using `FortranForm`. In order to avoid line breaks in the converted code, you can set the `PageWidth` of the current output stream to `Infinity` as follows:

```
SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth -> Infinity]
FortranForm@coscoefficient
```

> a1*D11 + a0*a1*D11 + (a1*a3*D11)/2. + (a2*a4*D11)/2. + (a3*a5*D11)/2. + (a4*a6*D11)/2. + (a5*a7*D11)/2. + (a6*a8*D11)/2. + d0*d1*D11 + b1*D12 + b0*b1*D12 + (b1*b3*D12)/2. + (b2*b4*D12)/2. + (b3*b5*D12)/2. + (b4*b6*D12)/2. + (b5*b7*D12)/2. + (b6*b8*D12)/2. + c1*D13 + c0*c1*D13 + (c1*c3*D13)/2. + (c2*c4*D13)/2. + b1*d0*D14 + d1*D14 + b0*d1*D14 + (b3*d1*D14)/2. + (b4*D14*d2)/2. + (d1*D11*d3)/2. + (b1*D14*d3)/2. + (b5*D14*d3)/2. + (b2*D14*d4)/2. + (b6*D14*d4)/2. + (D11*d2*d4)/2. + (b3*D14*d5)/2. + (b7*D14*d5)/2. + (D11*d3*d5)/2. + (b4*D14*d6)/2. + (b8*D14*d6)/2. + (D11*d4*d6)/2. + (b5*D14*d7)/2. + (D11*d5*d7)/2. + (b6*D14*d8)/2. + (D11*d6*d8)/2. + D14*e1 + a0*D14*e1 + (a3*D14*e1)/2. + (a4*D14*e2)/2. + (a1*D14*e3)/2. + (a5*D14*e3)/2. + (D12*e1*e3)/2. + (a2*D14*e4)/2. + (a6*D14*e4)/2. + (D12*e2*e4)/2. + (a3*D14*e5)/2. + (a7*D14*e5)/2. + (D12*e3*e5)/2. + (a4*D14*e6)/2. + (a8*D14*e6)/2. + (D12*e4*e6)/2. + (a5*D14*e7)/2. + (D12*e5*e7)/2. + (a6*D14*e8)/2. + (D12*e6*e8)/2. + D13*f0*f1 + (D13*f1*f3)/2. + (D13*f2*f4)/2. + (D13*f3*f5)/2. + (D13*f4*f6)/2. + (D13*f5*f7)/2. + (D13*f6*f8)/2. + D12*g0*g1 + (D12*g1*g3)/2. + (D12*g2*g4)/2. + (D12*g3*g5)/2. + (D12*g4*g6)/2. + (D12*g5*g7)/2. + (D12*g6*g8)/2. + D14*g1*h0 + D14*g0*h1 + (D14*g3*h1)/2. + D11*h0*h1 + (D14*g4*h2)/2. + (D14*g1*h3)/2. + (D14*g5*h3)/2. + (D11*h1*h3)/2. + (D14*g2*h4)/2. + (D14*g6*h4)/2. + (D11*h2*h4)/2. + D13*j0*j1 + (D13*j1*j3)/2. + (D13*j2*j4)/2. + (D13*j3*j5)/2. + (D13*j4*j6)/2. + (D13*j5*j7)/2. + (D13*j6*j8)/2.

Comment: After using FortranForm@coscoefficient, i do not want Hyphens (- ) in each line of expression. Thanks

Comment: @Amandeep I see. Those hyphens are introduced by FortranForm to account for line breaks, but one can avoid them by changing the page width option. I have just added that in my answer. Let me know if that works for you.